# Customer Creation from backend with store_id using magento REST api

Tags: java, magento, rest, magento-1.7

I was creating a magento customer using REST api. But the customer is being created with some default `store_id = 0` .

As a result when I try to login to the magento store I am getting error saying I

> Invalid login or password.

In the [magento customer creation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Customers-HTTPMethod-POST-customers) they haven't mentioned anything about this. How Can I do this? Any kind of heads up will be appreciated.

If I create a customer from front-end page then its getting *store_id=1* and for back-end its *store_id=0*. Both of them have same *website_id=1* So, when trying to login to magento I think we are trying to login different store.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the website ID instead it should take care of this for you.

For your reference

> Global: This refers to the entire installation.
>
> Website: Websites are ‘parents’ of stores.  A website consists of one or more stores. Websites can be set up to share customer data, or not to share any data
>
> Store (or store view group): Stores are ‘children’ of websites.  Products and Categories are managed on the store level.  A root category is configured for each store view group, allowing multiple stores under the same website to have totally different catalog structures.
> Store View: A store needs one or more store views to be browse-able in the front-end.  The catalog structure per store view will always be the same, it simply allows for multiple presentations of the data in the front.  90% of implementations will likely use store views to allow customers to switch between 2 or more languages.

Comment: I have added thw website_id too. but in database the store_id is different. And I have seen that the users created from magento site can login to the website easily. But the backend users cant. both of them have same website_id in table customer_entity.

Comment: @Elavarasan for example the xml http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Customers-HTTPMethod-POST-customers I have posted to magento.